# Библиотека jsoup. Соединение двух объектов типа Elements

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Коллеги, доброго вечера.

Пытаюсь спарсить [сайт погоды](http://www.realmeteo.ru/moscow/1/current) при помощи jsoup.

Собственно, хочу утащить значения погоды (Температура, сила ветра и тд).

```
  private static String url = "http://www.realmeteo.ru/moscow/1/current";

//Метод, парсящий страницу с погодой
private  static Document getPage() throws IOException {
    Document page = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url),3000);
    return page;
}

//Достаем с сайта нужную нам информацию
private static Elements getInfFromPagePrivate () throws IOException {
    Document page = getPage();
    Element getInformation = page.select("table[id=realdata]").first();
    Elements getMeteoData = getInformation.select("td[class=meteodata]");
    Elements getMeteoData_small = getInformation.select("td[class=meteodata_small]");

    return что-то;
}
```

Не могу понять, как вытащить всю инфу. Блок "ощущаемая температура" находится в meteodata_small, а вся остальная инфа в meteodata.

Вопрос: как мне либо вытащить всю нужную инфу в один объект типа Elements, либо как их объединить?
Очень прошу подсказать, сам что то никак..

Answer (score 0):

Ну что сказать, сидеть и что то делать ночью - так себе идея.
Выловил сам, в одном Elements. Как оказалось, можно указать нужные данные через запятую. Однако, если кто подскажет, как таки соединить 2 Elements в один, буду рад - вдруг пригодится.

```
Elements getMeteoData = getInformation.select("td[class=meteodata],td[class=meteodata_small]");
```

Comment: А что значит объединить "в один объект типа Elements"? `Elements` - это объект `List<Element>`, если я правильно помню. Соответственно, у вас результат уже в одном списке.